# Наложение звуковых дорожек

Tags: javascript, node.js

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой. Нужно наложить звуковую дорожку одну на другую. Есть ли какие-то библиотеки на *Node js*, через которые это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp3 \
  -filter_complex "[1]adelay=10000|10000[s1];[0:a][s1]amix=2[a]" \
  -map "[a]" -c:a copy 3.mp3
```

Команду не проверял, но вроде верная. Она берет звук из 1.mp3, миксует с 2.mp3 с задержкой (смещением) в 10 секунд и выдает результат в 3.mp3.

Запустить ffmpeg можно, например, [`child_process.exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback)